# VisualSVN Port Forwarding is Not Resolving

Tags: networking, port, port-forwarding, visualsvn-server

I am using the FreeDNS Update client to dynamically update the IP address of a subdomain. I can access https://localhost:8282/svn/ on the laptop but I cannot access it from https://my.domain.com:7430/svn/.

I enabled port forwarding on my router to connect the internal 8282 port to the external 7430 port. The request always times out. Interestingly, I have Glassfish running on the same machine under a different port using the same my.domain.com and it works fine. I also verified my.domain.com resolves to my router's IP address. Any idea why the request times out?

**Router Port Forwarding Setup:**

```
GlassFish (External Port: 7429; Internal Port: 8080; To IP Address: 192.168.1.122)
VisualSVN (External Port: 7430; Internal Port: 8282; To IP Address: 192.168.1.122)
```

The VisualSVN server is setup to listen to port 8282 over my.domain.com same as Glassfish.

Comment: What happens when you telnet to that port?

Comment: It is unable to make a connection. I setup the port forwarding the same way I did for Glassfish so I think that's ok. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you telnet to localhost:8282 or to my.domain.com:7430?  Because if the first works, and the second doesn't, then something's wrong with the port forwarding on the router.  What happens if you try to just map 8282 to 8282?

Comment: I tried telnet for both and they both just say connecting for a long time but don't do anything. If I am on the laptop hosting the SVN server, I can access localhost:8282 in my browser but my.domain.com:7430 doesn't work regardless of whether I'm on the laptop or a different computer outside my network. I think you're right. Please see above edits regarding port setup. I did try making the ports the same (7430) at one point but that didn't help either.

Comment: As a test - disable the Glassfish mapping and redo the VisualSVN mapping.

Comment: No dice. I disabled the Glassfish mapping and even tried making the ports both 8282 for VisualSVN and the request just times out. I agree with you. There is something funky going on with the port forwarding.

Comment: The only other thing I can think to do is this: disable SSL and try.  It's possible your cert is locked to the domain name localhost or somesuch and is causing your issue.  I doubt it, but I'd give it a try.